# Closing Access from Command Button

Tags: ms-access, command

Hey I am trying to fina a way to actually close acces from the close command button on a form. Is this possible? Right now it only closes the form and the user still has to exit out of the actual Access program. I want the user to be able to hit the command button and completely exit out of Access and go back to their desktop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The OnClick event needs to be: Application.Quit

I might have misunderstood or not explained well. You need to create a command button. Caption it say 'Quit' and make the OnClick event Application.Quit. Before Application.Quit you could insert a MsgBox function to explain what will happen and ask the user if this is really what they want. Come back if you want more help on this.

Just tried the quit button on one of my databases with another form open. The database close with no problem - no need to specially close the open form.

Answer (score 0):

I remember years ago I had to do this, and one of the things I learned is that you have to iterate through all your open forms and close them before you make the call to Application.Quit. I don't remember the details as to why I had to do it but I remember it solved a similar problem for me back then.